# Why this linux command can affect the environment variables?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

When I changed my current user to admin using

```
sudo su admin
```

I found that the environment variable changed too. What I intend to do is to **change my user to admin with the env not changed**.

Then I found a command as follows:

```
sudo bash -c "su - admin"
```

This command does indeed what I want, but I googled about `bash -c`, with no clue to why this command can do that for me. Could anyone give me a clear explanation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just do `sudo su - admin`

Comment: To leave the environment unmodified, you need `sudo -m`.  If `su - admin` is doing what you want, then leaving the environment unmodified is not what you want.

Comment: It tells me that I'n not allowed to execute '/bin/su - admin' as root. So could you just explain something about the relationship between your command and the env variables? Thanks @WilliamPursell

Comment: Beware that it is potentially a security risk to import your current environment into the super-user, as things like the path are intentionally slimmed down to prevent unknowingly running the wrong program.  Many sysadmins always invoke commands with their prefixes (*eg* `/bin/ls`, `/sbin/ip`) to reduce the chance of this, but it's easy to be caught out.

Answer (score 1):

first you should read the sudo manpage and set theses options in the /etc/sudoers file or you can do it interactively (see second below).

default sudoers file may not preserve the existing $USER environment unless you set the config options to do so. You'll want to read up on env_reset because depending on your OS distribution the sudo config will be different in most cases.

I dont mean to be terse but I am on a mobile device..

I do not recommend using sudo su .. for anything. whomever is sharing sudo su with the public is a newb, and you can accomplish the same cleaner with just sudo.

with your example whats happining is you are starting a subshell owned by the original user ("not admin") . you are starting the subshell with -c "string" sudo has the equivelant of the shell's -c using -s which either reads the shell from the arg passed to -s or the shell defined in the passwd file.

second you should use:

```
    $ sudo -u admin -E -s
```

much cleaner right ? :)

```
    -u sets the user, obviously 
    -s we just explained
    -E preserves the orig user env
```

see for yourself just

```
    $ echo $HOME    # should show the original users /home/orig_user
    $ env
```

your original env is preserved with none of that sudo su ugliness.

if you were interested in simulating a users login without preserving the env..

```
    $ sudo -u user -i
```

or for root:

Might require -E depending on distro sudoers file

```
    $ sudo -s
```

or

```
    $ sudo -i 

    -i simulates the login and uses the users env.
```

hopefully this helps and someone will kindly format it to be more readable since im on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

bash with -c argument defines below.

-c string

If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok